# Creating private extension for View's subviews and constants in separate file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, constants

I have my View which is very complex structure having many different subviews.
Up to now, I have had them all in one file but it became as big as over 400 lines of code (I use SwiftLint to check code rules breaks) so I thought of moving those subviews and constants to separate file and creating an extension.
What I want is that extension to be visible only for the particular view it extends but also that this extension could be kept in separate file to reduce the lines of code in original view's file:

Example:

**Up to now I had a situation like this:**

`File SampleView`:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SampleView.SampleViewConstants.sampleImage
        }
    }
}

private extension SampleView {
    static var sampleImage: some View {
        Image(SampleViewConstants.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(height: SampleViewConstants.imageBackgroundFrameHeight)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    
    struct SampleViewConstants {
        static let imageName: String = "sampleImageName"
        static let imageBackgroundFrameHeight: CGFloat = 56
    }
}
```

**What I want:**

`File SampleView`:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SampleView.SampleViewConstants.sampleImage
        }
    }
}
```

`File SampleViewConstants`:

```
private extension SampleView {
    static var sampleImage: some View {
        Image(SampleViewConstants.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(height: SampleViewConstants.imageBackgroundFrameHeight)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    
    struct SampleViewConstants {
        static let imageName: String = "sampleImageName"
        static let imageBackgroundFrameHeight: CGFloat = 56
    }
}
```

Unfortunately XCode tells me that my `SampleView` does not see `SampleViewConstants` structure because it is marked as private and only valid at file scope.
Maybe another way to solve it?

Comment: Extension visibility doesn't work that way. You should find another way of splitting up your code.

Comment: @Sweeper I see that it does not work like that. Do you have any suggestions to make it work remaining encapsulation and moving extension to another file?

Comment: Yes. Just remove the `private`. Private means, the extension is only visible in that file.

Comment: @baronfac But then this extension won't be encapsulated and be visible in other views

Comment: That's why this approach is not ideal. Create custom views for the subviews to create smaller code chunks.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect case for a `protocol`

Comment: Keep it simple, create simple separate views, easier test and iterate over. If you want to add structs inside your view create them as non-private (internal) extensions. Yes these internal extensions would be accessible outside the view but that's ok. If you really want to hide it create it as a Swift Package and `internal` wouldn't be accessible, only public would be accessible.

Comment: @loremipsum could you elaborate on that? Sample use of protocol in my example?

Answer (score 0):

To organize your code you can use @ViewBuilder:

```
@ViewBuilder func sampleView(name: String = "sampleImageName", height: CGFloat = 56) -> some View {
    let imageName = name
    let imageBackgroundFrameHeight = height
    
    VStack {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .frame(height: imageBackgroundFrameHeight)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

and call the function in the body:

```
sampleView() //This will take the default values(imageName = "sampleImageName" and imageBackgroundFrameHeight = 56)

sampleView(name: "NewName", height: 80) //This will take on new values "NewName" and height of 80
```

You can also use custom view modifiers like so:

```
struct Shadowfy: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content // The content is a view you want to put your custom modifier on like my shadowfy custom modifier that puts shadows on views so I don't have to repeat this code
            .shadow(color: .red, radius: 1, x: 1, y: -1)
            .shadow(color: .green, radius: 2, x: -2, y: 2)
    }
}
extension View { 
    func shadowfy() -> some View { 
        self.modifier(Shadowfy())
     }
 }
```

and then you just use it like this:

```
Text("MyText")
    .shadowfy()
```